# Make PrimeFaces messages disappear after 5 seconds

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My new task is to have PrimeFaces `<p:messages>` dissappear after 5 seconds after appearing. I haven't found any specific setting for that in PF's user guide, nor on their webpage. I thought maybe I could bind an JavaScript event to `<p:messages>` appearing, but don't know where to start.

My messages are in the Template:

```
<p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" rendered="#{not suppressMessages}" />
```

and render such an empty `<div>` in DOM:

```
<div id="messages" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>
```

and full:

```
<div id="messages" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite">
  <div class="ui-messages-info ui-corner-all">
   <a class="ui-messages-close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp();return false;" href="#">
   <span class="ui-messages-info-icon"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
       <span class="ui-messages-info-summary">Sample info message</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know of a jQuery or Primefaces specific solution?

**Solution**

I've found the combination of jQuery and `<p:ajaxStatus>` to be the solution to my problem. I've added:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="setTimeout(function() { $('.ui-messages').slideUp(); }, 5000); PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
```

to my `<p:ajaxStatus>` and some jQuery in case of non ajax messages.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if(!$.trim($(".ui-messages").html())==''){
       //console.log("messages found");
       setTimeout(function() {$('.ui-messages').slideUp();}, 5000);
   } else {
       //console.log("messages not found");
   }    
});
```

Thanks for the lead BalusC!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf) to hook on ajax start, complete, success and error events. You can then just fire a `setTimeout()` on a `slideUp()` of the messages.

```
<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete="setTimeout(function() { $('.ui-messages').slideUp(); }, 5000)" />
```

Or, more generically, you could also use jQuery's [`$.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) for this.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ui-messages').slideUp();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: `<p:ajaxStatus>` idea is nice, the thing is, I'm using `<p:ajaxStatus>` for a wait symbol already. Often I'm also using `global="false"` in order not to display the wait.gif - in this case `<p:ajaxStatus>` solution won't work. Sometimes I use `<p:messages>` as greetings (at login for instance) and these events are not ajax.