# Remove message from h:outputText ofter time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using this message to display mail status

```
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{mailhandler.result}"  />
```

I'm interested how I can remove the text after 5 seconds from the screen?

Comment: `setTimeout` and some jQuery?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Can you show me some code sample how to use it?

Comment: This is interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20132008/2459449

Comment: Yes, but I don't use Primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class so it's easier to refer to

```
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{mailhandler.result}"  styleClass="timeout" />
```

Then add JavaScript/jQuery:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     $('.timeout').toggle();
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: Not familiar with F12 key in webbrowser yet, Peter? It opens a new world full of potential clues :)

Comment: @PeterPenzov The arguments were flipped - try now.